# node js database connection getting http 405 and 404 errors

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, database

I am trying to connect my create account form to the mySql database using node js, however I don't understand why my code is not finding the correct path?

I am running 'http-server' and then 'npm start' commands in separate terminals to run and test the webpage

createAccount.html

```
<!--allow user to create account
    -store user login details
-->

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Create account</title>

  <script></script>

</head>

<body>
  

  <h1>Create account</h1>

  <form id="createAccount-form" method='POST' action='/createAccount'>

    <label for="username"></label>
    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" name="username" required>
    <p></p>

    <label for="email"></label>
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required >
    <p></p>

    <label for="password"></label>
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
    <p></p>

    <label for="Confpassword"></label>
    <input type="password" id="Confpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
    <p></p>

    <input type="checkbox" onclick=togglePword()> Show Password
    <p></p>

    <button id="createAccountbtn" type="submit">Create account</button>
    
  </form>


</body>

</html>
```

createAccountConn.js

```
//CREATE ACCOUNT


//add a route to createAccount
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const express = require('express');
const ap = express();
const path = require('path');
require("dotenv").config();

//establish db connection
const db = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 100,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT
});

db.getConnection((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Connected to MySQL database successfully');
});


ap.use(express.json()); //read req.body.<parameter>
ap.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})); //pass form data

ap.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'Niche.com')));
ap.get('/',(res,req)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'Niche.com','index.html'))
});


ap.post('/createAccount', async (req,res) => {

  const username = req.body.username;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password,10);

  //validate form inputs
  if (!username || !email || !password){
    return res.status(400).send('Empty fields')
  };

  db.execute(
    'INSERT INTO user_login (id, username, email, password) VALUES (0,?,?,?)',
    [0, username, email, hashPassword],
    (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).send('Error occured while creating account')
        }
    //redirect to user homepage
    res.send('Account created successufully')
    res.redirect('/')
    }
  );

  
});

ap.listen(8080, () => {
        console.log('Server started on port 8080')
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "niche.com",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "Index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node createAccountConn.js"
  },

.....
```

I've checked the right ports are being opened

This is the error I am getting in the terminal:

```
[2023-04-30T03:13:03.942Z]  "POST /createAccount" Error (404): "Not found"
```

and in the network tab of inspector mode:

```
ailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()
```

but I don't understand why its nto finding the right path

Comment: Hi @RolandOlajide, can you share a bit more such as the errors printed in both your terminal and the Network tab of the browser? The only 2 obvious bugs I can notice is: Your prepared statement has 3 `?` but you pass in 4 arguments, `password` is not defined (Should be `const password = req.body.password` instead)